# Case integrated stand offs? Safe to use without risers?

Tags: motherboard, case

Is it safe to use the integrated stand-offs here? The case did not come with enough brass screw-in stand offs for my motherboard. I don't want to short circuit everything before I even turn it on.

[image: Screen Shot 1]

The case (above) is Bitfenix Merc Alpha

It is a M-ATX Asus board that I need to pop in

Thank you.

Comment: If you have enough risers installed then you have nothing to fear. Check the manual for the case and/or the motherboard to determine how many you need.  **You can determine how many you need based on the placement of the motherboard in the case**

Answer (score 1):

All those stand-offs appear to be in the standard ATX/uATX screw positions, so you just need to add whichever extra stand-offs are required by your motherboard.

It doesn't hurt to double-check that all the built-in stand-offs are either outside the perimeter of the motherboard or that they match up to screw holes in the motherboard, but you should be fine.